# Find duplicates and check for duplicate elements inside the object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains some objects
I want to find duplicate names in the array
After finding the duplicate names of each duplicate name, I should also check their age.
In addition to having the same name, if the age is not the same but the names are the same, save it and give me an error only if the name is the same and the same age.
My array has duplicate names that are not the same age
Now the program I wrote gives an error and should not give an error because the names are the same but their age is not the same and should be saved and not done correctly
After searching the array, I found duplicate name. Two duplicate Liam names are equal in age. Give an error in the console, but if the age is not equal, do not make a mistake and it will be
Thank you for helping me answer

```js
const data = [
     {id: 1,name: "Liam",age: 20},
     {id: 2,name: "Liam",age: 18},
     {id: 3,name: "Noah",age: 20},
     {id: 4,name: "Noah",age: 18},
     {id: 5,name: "Elijah",age: 18}
]

    function checked() {
        const toFindDuplicates = arry => arry.filter((item, index) => arry.indexOf(item) !== index);
        const getName = data.map(item => item.name)
        const duplicateName = toFindDuplicates(getName)
        console.log(duplicateName);
        if (duplicateName.length > 0) {
            const newArray = []
            const filters = data.filter(x => duplicateName.includes(x.name))
            filters.forEach(item => newArray.push(item.age))
            console.log(filters);
            const duplicateAge = toFindDuplicates(newArray)
            if (!!duplicateName.length) {
                console.log("error");
            } else {
                return console.log("save");;
            }
        } else {
            return console.log("save");;
        }
    }
    checked()
```

Comment: The explanation is really confusing. Could you clarify the use-case?

Comment: You have already asked this question [3 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69537365/find-objects-that-have-duplicate-names-inside-the-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @JeremyThille No, this question is different

Comment: @SinanYaman After searching the array, I found duplicate `name`. Two duplicate Liam names are equal in `age`. Give an error in the console, but if the age is not equal, do not make a mistake and it will be saved.

Comment: @SinanYaman Did you understand my request?

Comment: It's the "same" problem just with another test criteria for duplicate yes or no...

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): Add a [mcve] which involves sample input and the expected output. Also please add some structure to your question. A wall of text doesn't really help to understand your problem.

Comment: @Good Include your expected results, and realistically your question is really unclear.

Comment: @slashroot In my array, the names Noah and Liam are duplicates, and each is repeated twice.
I want to check the age of the first `Noah` with the second `Noah`.
Also check the age of the first `Liam` with the second `Liam`.
If they are the same age, give an error, otherwise print it in the save console.

Comment: So just like the answer that @SinanYaman gave below. Instead of save/error being printed its true/false.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you simply want to detect if your data has the same `name` `age` pair. You can check it like this:

```js
const data1 = [
     {id: 1,name: "Liam",age: 20},
     {id: 2,name: "Liam",age: 18},
     {id: 3,name: "Noah",age: 20},
     {id: 4,name: "Noah",age: 18},
     {id: 5,name: "Elijah",age: 18}
]

const data2 = [
     {id: 1,name: "Liam",age: 20},
     {id: 2,name: "Liam",age: 18},
     {id: 3,name: "Noah",age: 20},
     {id: 4,name: "Noah",age: 18},
     {id: 5,name: "Elijah",age: 18},
     {id: 6,name: "Liam",age: 18},
]

const duplicateExists = arr => {
  let error = false, obj = {}
  arr.forEach(el => {
    if(!error){
      const {name,age} = el
      if(obj[name]) {
        error = obj[name] === age
      }
      obj[name] = age
    }
  } ,{})
  return error
}

console.log(duplicateExists(data1))
console.log(duplicateExists(data2))
```

Comment: @slashroot In my array, the names Noah and Liam are duplicates, and each is repeated twice.
I want to check the age of the first `Noah` with the second `Noah`.
Also check the age of the first `Liam` with the second `Liam`.
If they are the same age, give an error, otherwise print it in the save console.

Comment: That is what this code does?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm checking now, can we modify my code and do the same? And have my code changed less?

Comment: You just copy the function, and it will return a `false`/`true` boolean, which you can use anyway you want.

Answer (score 1):

For an `O(N)` single-pass solution you could consider utilizing a [**Map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that uses the name as a key and a **[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set)** of previously seen ages corresponding to the name as the value, since lookup into a Set is `O(1)`:

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, name: "Liam", age: 20},
    {id: 2, name: "Liam", age: 18},
    {id: 3, name: "Noah", age: 20},
    {id: 4, name: "Noah", age: 18},
    {id: 5, name: "Elijah", age: 18},
];

const hasDuplicates = arr => {
    const nameToAges = new Map();
    for (const {_, name, age} of arr) {
        if (nameToAges.has(name)) {
            if (nameToAges.get(name).has(age)) {
                return true;
            }
            nameToAges.get(name).add(age);
        } else {
            nameToAges.set(name, new Set([age]));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("Two elements exist with same name and age:");
console.log(hasDuplicates(data));
```

Try it out [**here**](https://replit.com/@ShashSinha1/UsefulInsignificantBudgetrange#index.js).

Answer (score 0):

[**Edit**: Removed the complex solution]

If you just want to check for any duplicate in the array, using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) simplifies things a lot. Here's a more generic function to check for duplicates on any (combination of) key(s) in an array of Objects.

```js
const [data, data2] = getExampleData();
console.log(`hasDuplicatesForKeys(data, 'name', 'age'): ${ 
  hasDuplicatesForKeys(data, 'name', 'age') }`);
console.log(`hasDuplicatesForKeys(data2, 'name', 'age'): ${ 
  hasDuplicatesForKeys(data2, 'name', 'age') }`);
// name and id
console.log(`hasDuplicatesForKeys(data2, 'name', 'id'): ${
  hasDuplicatesForKeys(data2, 'name', 'id') }`);
// single key
console.log(`hasDuplicatesForKeys(data2, 'name'): ${
  hasDuplicatesForKeys(data2, 'name') }`);
console.log(`hasDuplicatesForKeys(data, 'id'): ${
  hasDuplicatesForKeys(data, 'id') }`);

/**
 * Generic function to check for duplicate Object 
 * on certain keys within an array of objects
 * @param data {Array} The array
 * @param keys {string[]} The keys to filter on 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function hasDuplicatesForKeys(data, ...keys) {
  let check = new Set();
  data.forEach( d => check.add( keys.map( k => d[k] ).join(``) ) );
  return [...check].length < data.length;
}

// keep data out of sight
function getExampleData() {
  return [
    [
     {id: 1, name: "Liam", age: 20},
     {id: 2, name: "Liam", age: 18},
     {id: 3, name: "Noah", age: 20},
     {id: 3, name: "Noah", age: 20},
     {id: 4, name: "Noah", age: 18},
     {id: 5, name: "Elijah", age: 18},
     {id: 12, name: "Elijah", age: 18} ],
   [
     {id: 1, name: "Liam", age: 20},
     {id: 2, name: "Liam", age: 18},
     {id: 3, name: "Noah", age: 20},
     {id: 4, name: "Noah", age: 18},
     {id: 5, name: "Elijah", age: 18} ],
  ];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The description of your issue is not entirely clear to me, but it sounds like you want to group the items based on name. Then do some checks based on the resulting groups.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Liam",   age: 18 },
  { id: 2, name: "Liam",   age: 18 },
  { id: 3, name: "Noah",   age: 20 },
  { id: 4, name: "Noah",   age: 18 },
  { id: 5, name: "Elijah", age: 18 },
];

const peopleByName = groupBy(data, person => person.name);
for (const [name, people] of peopleByName) {
  const isDuplicate = people.length > 1;
  const haveSameAge = people.every(person => person.age == people[0].age);
  
  if (isDuplicate && haveSameAge) {
    console.log(name, "is a duplicate");
  } else if (isDuplicate) {
    console.error(name, "duplicate with different ages");
  } else {
    console.log(name, "is unique");
  }
}

// helper
function groupBy(iterable, fnKey) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = fnKey(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}
```